# Extender duración de sesión en PHP

Tags: php

Después de haberse logueado en mi sitio, en mi código establezco una variable de sesión de esta forma:

```
$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $user;
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
```

Como pueden ver NO guardo la contraseña. Entonces, cuando un usuario tiene 15 mnutos de inactividad (puede ser que haya ido a hacer otras cosas) se le cierra la sesión ¿Como solucionar este problema?

Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: tienes alguna idea de como solucionarlo??? creo que la pregunta correcta seria como extender tiempo de session de usuarios en php o como controlar el tiempo de session de usuarios en php??? creo que debes editar la pregunta y reformularla. saludos.

Comment: Como dice @FranciscoNúñez, parece mas un problema de tiempo de guardado de la propia sesion.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Ya he modificado la pregunta, gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mediante `PHP` o modificando el propio `.htaccess`
**PHP:**

```php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6300); 
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 6300);
ini_set('session.cache_expire', 6300);
ini_set('session.name', 'MiSesion');
```

Todo esto antes del `session_start()`;

**.htaccess**

```
 php_value session.save_path /home/server/.miSesion
 php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 6300
 php_value session.cookie_lifetime 6300
 php_value session.cache_expire 6300
 php_value session.name MiDominio
```

Comment: ini_set('session.name', 'MiSesion'); Aquí debo poner mi sesión o algo? O así tal cual como está?

Comment: Para adaptarlo a tu propia sesion: Echale una ojeada a la documentación https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime, es bastante sencillo de implementar. Aún así veo que no  has compartido tu session start, dónde podrías crear un iterador que funcione hasta que termine o el usuario lo cierre.